# Need to get the values of the row in a table with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, odoo

I have defined a table and I need to get the values of one row when I'm clicking a button (located in the same row) using JavaScript. I'm trying to use the attributte onclick() and calling to a function but it does not work.
This is my template code:

```
<table id="mi_tablica" class="table table-striped table-borderless">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>#</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Price</th>
   <th>Image</th>
   <th id="th_product_id">Id</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
    <t t-set = "contador" t-value="1" />
    <t t-foreach="productos" t-as="p">
     <tr>
      <td><p><span t-esc="contador" /></p></td>
      <td><p><span t-esc="p.name" /></p></td>
      <td><p><span t-esc="p.list_price" /></p></td>
      <td><img t-att-src="'/web/image/product.template/%s/image' % p.id" width="96" height="65"/></td>
      <td id="td_product_id"><p><span t-esc="p.id" /></p></td>
      <td><input id="btn_delete_product" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="borrar_registro()" value="Eliminar"/></td>
     </tr>
     <t t-set = "contador" t-value="contador+1" />
    </t>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks for reading!

[image: This is how the table is]

I tryed to implement the function but I'm not able to get the selected row to obtain the values, and then assign those values into a variable.

```
function borrar_registro(){
    var table = document.getElementById('mi_tablica');
    selected = table.getElementsByClassName('selected');
    //Here i need to get the selected object and asign to a variable the values
}
```

Comment: where `borrar_registro()` is defined ?

Comment: Is an empty function defined in static/src/js/website.js. @DevsiOdedra

Comment: which value you needed on click ?

Comment: I need to get the <td id="td_product_id"><p><span t-esc="p.id" /></p></td> value of the row. I need to get the value from p.id @Devsi Odedra

Comment: but here no value for p.id

Comment: "does not work" how exactly? We can't see what code you tried, or what went wrong when you tried it. We can't fix an unidentified problem with invisible code. Nor can we read your mind. Please show your attempt and explain the issue in more detail, including any errors you see the in the console etc. If you have extra info, please add it to your question using the "edit" button - don't post it in the comments. Thanks.

Comment: Okey, I'm going to explain it better. I have created a table that every row is filled by an array called "productos". Each row has some fields and a button. When I click this button called "btn_delete_product" I need to obtain those row values and save them into a variable, that's all. I was trying to do it using onclick() atribute and a JS function but I can't obtain the row values by a simple click in the button. Edited the post to see how the rows looks. Thanks! @Devsi Odedra

Comment: Explained, do you understand now the issue? If not, I would try to explain it again. @ADyson

Comment: Do you mind if I repeat the last part of the previous comment: **If you have extra info, please add it to your question using the "edit" button - don't post it in the comments**. You've added some stuff to your question, but all this explanation should be placed there too.

Comment: "I can't obtain the row values by a simple click"...again, please show what code you tried in order to achieve it. If you "can't" do something then presumably there's some code which is causing you a problem. We can't fix what we can't see. I assume you've researched how you might select other elements from the same row of a HTML table, and then tried to implement it?

Comment: Posted my try to obtain the selected row, but I don't know how to get the values of that row. Any idea? @ADyson

Comment: You need to get the specific row, not the whole table. HTML is a hierarchical tree structure. You can go up the DOM tree from the current element (always `this`) in an event listener function and get its parents. When you go up to the row level, you can then find other elements within that using selectors, but restricted to the scope of the row element. I'd have hoped some basic research would have led you to existing examples of this kind of technique.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must to explain in more detail your question but I understand what are you trying to achieve...

I imagine that you have a QWeb in your module of Odoo located in the static folder.

In this example I will replicate what is the right way of how to do it.

> 1. In your ***static*** folder you have the following structure:
>
>    - static/src/xml/my_module_qweb_template.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <templates xml:space="preserve">
        <t t-name="product_example_template">
             <table id="mi_tablica" class="table table-striped table-borderless">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Price</th>
       <th>Image</th>
       <th id="th_product_id">Id</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
       <tbody>
        <t t-set = "contador" t-value="1" />
        <t t-foreach="productos" t-as="p">
         <tr>
          <td><p><span t-esc="contador" /></p></td>
          <td><p><span t-esc="p.name" /></p></td>
          <td><p><span t-esc="p.list_price" /></p></td>
          <td><img t-att-src="'/web/image/product.template/%s/image' % p.id" width="96" height="65"/></td>
          <td id="td_product_id"><p><span t-esc="p.id" /></p></td>
          <td><input id="btn_delete_product" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="borrar_registro()" value="Eliminar"/></td>
         </tr>
         <t t-set = "contador" t-value="contador+1" />
        </t>
      </tbody>
    </table>
        </t>
    </templates>
```

> 2. In your ***static*** folder you have the following:
>
>    - static/src/js/my_module_script.js

```
odoo.define('product.example', function (require) {
    "use strict";
    let core = require('web.core');
    let Widget = require('web.Widget');
    let qweb = core.qweb;
    let rpc = require('web.rpc');
    var ProductClientsViewExample = Widget.extend({
        template: 'product_example_template',
        events: { 
            'click #btn_delete_product': 'action_remove_product', 
        }),
        action_remove_product:  function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            let current_item = $(event.currentTarget);
            console.log("Do whatever you want with your current_item --->", current_item);
        }, 
    });
    core.action_registry.add('tag.product.client.example', ProductClientsViewExample);

    return {
        ProductClientsViewExample: ProductClientsViewExample,
    };
});
```

> 3. In your ***views*** folder you have a file my_product_client_view.xml with the following:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <odoo>
        <data>
            <template id="assets_backend" name="Product Example" inherit_id="web.assets_backend"> 
                <xpath expr="//link[last()]" position="after">
                     <script type="text/javascript" src="/my_module/static/src/js/my_module_script.js" />
                </xpath>
            </template>
            <!-- Client Action For Menu Product Client Example -->
            <record id="action_product_clients_example" model="ir.actions.client">
                <field name="name">Product Client Example</field>
                <field name="tag">tag.product.client.example</field>
            </record>
        </data>
    </odoo>
```

> 4. In your ***__manifest__.py*** file you have the following under *data* list:

```
'views/my_product_client_view.xml'
```

> 5. In your ***__manifest__.py*** file you have the following under *qweb* list:

```
"static/src/xml/*.xml",
```

If you don't have your module like my example above, I don't know what the hell are you doing with Odoo but only You and God knows...

And I recommend you to read the official documentation:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/web.html